# How to track progress of a student in a Learning Management System

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design, cakephp-3.0

I'm working on an LMS for a client. The top level table is Certificates. The next level down is Courses and below that is Activities. An Activity may be a video, a slide, or a quiz.

Storing those relations is easy and not an issue.

If a student/user signs up for a certificate, I need to track that student's progress through the certificate. So I need to have a unique version of the Certificate and all it's children so I can know what their progress is for each Activity, Course and Certificate. One other consideration is that the student can complete the certificate multiple times.

I tried a Progress table with `user_id, certificate_id, course_id, activity_id` and completed but it doesn't handle signing up for the certificate multiple times. In that same table I tried referring to the `certificates_users_id` to attempt to establish a unique top level reference for that user & certificate but I'm having trouble joining it together.

I want to be able to grab that user's In Progress Certificates and know exactly which activities & courses in it have been completed by that user.

Comment: Well, I guess you would have a table of enrollments, which might have the certificate_id, the user_id, and the date of enrollment - on the assumption that the same user cannot enroll for same course, twice, at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add a new field say `attempt_number` in your progress table, the keys: `user_id, certificate_id, attempt_number` together can make a primary key and this way you can handle the scenario in which a user completes a certificate multiple times. You can start with attempt_number as 1 and increment it the next time user does the same certification.

It also tracks the history of each time the certification is completed, say a new Activity got added in a course after the user completes the certification, that can be tracked easily.